# proper way to develop plugins for cakephp using git

Tags: git, cakephp

I want to develop a plugin for CakePHP and host it on GitHub. I want to have a master branch with the actual files of the plugin, excluding all the CakePHP lib and misc app files and folders. At the same time, I need to develop with the whole CakePHP framework for testing. How can I keep the two separate using Git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the `git submodule` command.

Assuming you already have started on the plugin, make a clone of cakephp, bake a new project and then `git submodule add githubrepo app/Plugin/Yourpluginname` into that project.

Whenever you `cd` in `app/Plugin/Yourpluginname` git will know you're working in a different project, try `git status`, push, pull, etc.